# How does the fluid approximation affect the geodesic equation?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, geodesics

So general relativity strictly speaking is a theory where only fields are allowed. To make calculations in it we often use the fluid approximation and think the matter surrounding us instead of stars, planets, dust, vacuum, etc as a continuum. I'm thinking in terms of the [FLRW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) metric:

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) (\frac{d \bar{r}^2}{1-K\bar{r}^2} + \bar{r}^2 d\Omega^2)$$

it's stress energy tensor is given by an [ideal fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Stress%E2%80%93energy_of_a_fluid_in_equilibrium):

$$ T^{\mu \nu } = (\rho c^2+P)u^{\mu}u^{\nu}+Pg^{\mu\nu} + \text{Error}$$

Since:

$$ \frac{1}{\kappa}  G^{\mu \nu} = T^{\mu \nu} = (\rho c^2+P)u^{\mu}u^{\nu}+Pg^{\mu\nu} + \text{Error}$$

where $\kappa$ is the coupling constant, $G^{\mu \nu}$ is the Einstein tensor. What is the order of the error in:

$$ds^2 = 0 + \text{Error}'$$

### Question

How does one determine the magnitude of the error the fluid approximation introduces?

Comment: $\kappa$ on other side of EFE

Comment: @Eletie thanks and fixed :)